# Loop back to beginning of code if input doesn't match REGEX | Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm trying to make my code loop back to the beginning until the user inputs something that matches the `REGEX` pattern.

For example:

```
userInput = raw_input('Enter text :')

if re.match("REGEX", userInput):
    #Do something
```

**If the `REGEX` pattern does not match userInput, the code should ask them to enter userInput again until it matches the `REGEX` and there forth will do something**. I am assuming a `for loop` is needed but I am not sure how to use it with `REGEX`.

<<< UPDATE >>>

**Solution** thanks to VKS:

```
while True:
    userInput = raw_input('Enter text :')
    if re.match("REGEX", userInput):
         break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    userInput = raw_input('Enter text :')
    if re.match("REGEX", userInput):
         break
```

You can do this simply

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag, set it to true, set it to false when a match occurs

```
do_loop = True

while do_loop:

    userInput = raw_input('Enter text :')

    if re.match("REGEX", userInput):
       #Do something
       do_loop = False
```